# update a dataset values with gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataset

i have a grid view :

Discount.aspx

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3" 
        CellSpacing="1" GridLines="None">
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#594B9C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#33276A" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

and i fill it through dataset at the Discount.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Discount : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DBservices db2 = new DBservices();
        SqlConnection con = db2.connect("storeConnectionString"); 
        string SelectSTR = "SELECT * FROM Items";  
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectSTR, con);  


        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView2.DataSource = ds;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int price;
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            if (Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[4]) > Convert.ToInt32(minamount.Text))
            {
                price = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);
                price= price*((100- Convert.ToInt32(discountrate.Text))/100);
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[4] = price;
                GridView2.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

as you can see i was trying to update the the Price Column in the dataset and than update the gridview but the problem is that nothing change at the gridview....

thank you and have a nice day

Comment: Try my updated answer code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to rebind the grid with datasource:

```
 GridView2.DataSource = ds; //missing

  GridView2.DataBind();
```

You are missing the first line in the button click event:

Declare a global data adapter;

then after changing value:

```
   da.update() // Saves Changes to database
```

**Updated2:**

```
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectSTR, con);  

    make changes to dataset

   da.update() // save changes to database
```

**NOte : declare dataadapter outside so that it will be accessible in both the methods**

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the datasource of your gridview on button click. Beware that these changes are not updated to the database (your call).

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int price;
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        if (Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[4]) > Convert.ToInt32(minamount.Text))
        {
            price = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);
            price= price*((100- Convert.ToInt32(discountrate.Text))/100);
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[4] = price;
            Gridview2.DataSource=ds;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```